# Hide Qualtrics library calendar until input field gets focus / is clicked

Tags: javascript, calendar, qualtrics

I need to show the calendar only when the date input field gets focus.

I have tried various options but I still c'ant get my code to work.
Can I not somehow reference the input field and render the calendar on an event rather than on the page's OnLoad event?

Library script below:

```
<script>
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() {
  var qid = this.questionId;
  var calid = qid + '_cal';
  var y = QBuilder('div');

  $(y).setStyle({
    clear: 'both'
  });

  var d = QBuilder(
    'div', {
      className: 'yui-skin-sam'
    }, [QBuilder('div', {
      id: calid
    }),
        y
       ]);

  var c = this.questionContainer;
  c = $(c).down('.QuestionText');
  c.appendChild(d);

  var cal1 = new YAHOO.widget.Calendar(calid);
  cal1.render();

  var input = $('QR~' + qid);
  $(input).setStyle({
    marginTop: '20px',
    width: '150px'
  });

  var p = $(input).up();
  var x = QBuilder('div');
  $(x).setStyle({
    clear: 'both'
  });
  p.insert(x, {
    position: 'before'
  });

  cal1.selectEvent.subscribe(function(e, dates) {
    var date = dates[0][0];
    if (date[1] < 10)
      date[1] = '0' + date[1];
    if (date[2] < 10)
      date[2] = '0' + date[2];
    input.value = date[2] + '/' + date[1] + '/' + date[0];
  })
});
</script>
```

I load the following in the survey header:

```
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/yui/2.9.0/build/calendar/assets/skins/sam/calendar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/yui/2.9.0/build/yahoo-dom-event/yahoo-dom-event.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/yui/2.9.0/build/calendar/calendar-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You should post your html as well. Might be a good idea to make a plunk or some working example of your code.

Answer (score 1):

Modify the end of your script to the following (the 4 new lines are marked with //add this):

```
var calDiv = $(qid).down('div.yui-skin-sam');   //add this
calDiv.hide();  //add this
cal1.selectEvent.subscribe(function(e, dates) {
    var date = dates[0][0];
    if (date[1] < 10)
      date[1] = '0' + date[1];
    if (date[2] < 10)
      date[2] = '0' + date[2];
    input.value = date[2] + '/' + date[1] + '/' + date[0];
    calDiv.hide();  //add this
});

$(input).on('focus', function(event) {  calDiv.show();  }); //add this
```